# Why i can't apply function on BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

After scraping website I once applied the function find_all
But cannot apply once more

why?

```
>>> from requests import get
>>> with get(url) as conn:
        print(conn)
>>> soap = BeautifulSoup(conn.content,"lxml")
>>> MAIN_DATA = soap.find_all("div",{"class" :"SOMETHING"})
>>> MAIN_DATA.find(SOMETHING) # WHY I CANNOT APPLY find and findall Function to this object

                 THANKS
```

Comment: Try identing the lines to be within the with block

Comment: SRY I tried this But not working

Comment: I have to remove the attribute(div on the basis of class name)

Comment: `find_all` returns a list, you have to loop on MAIN_DATA if you want to find something on each result

Comment: I have to find a specific "div" on the basis of "class name" and I have to decompose it

Comment: so maybe you just need `soap.find("div",{"class" :"SOMETHING"})` to get ONE result

Comment: ya, but it doesn't work "MAIN_DATA.find(SOMETHING)"

Comment: MAIN_DATA = soap.find_all("div",{"class" :"SOMETHING"}) #taken all the info in MAIN_DATA object and but i can't use MAIN_DATA.find()

Comment: @Shashank Singh code worked

Comment: Thanks for your help @PRMoureu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
for divs in MAIN_DATA:
    divs.find(SOMETHING)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Shashank Singh .

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to loop on your find_all:

```
for div in soap.find_all("div")
```

Comment: MAIN_DATA = soap.find_all("div",{"class" :"SOMETHING"}) #used it once

Comment: MAIN_DATA.find(SOMETHING) # I can use find_all or find more